# Что предпочесть - функцию с переменным количеством аргументов или передачу массива/вектора указателей void*?

Tags: c++, функции, передача-параметров, аргументы

Пожалуйста подскажите, что лучше, **эллипсис** или **вектор void указателей**?
По-идее одно и то же, но может в кого производительность более лучше? Спасибо.

Пример эллипсиса:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdarg> // требуется для использования эллипсиса

double findAverage(int first, ...)
{
    // Обработка первого значения
    double sum = first;
 
    // Мы получаем доступ к эллипсису через va_list, поэтому объявляем переменную этого типа
    va_list list;
 
    // Инициализируем va_list используя va_start. Первый параметр - это список, который нужно инициализировать.
    // Второй параметр - это последний параметр, который не является эллипсисом
    va_start(list, first);
 
    int count = 1;
    // Бесконечный цикл
    while (1)
    {
        // Используем va_arg для получения параметров из эллипсиса.
        // Первый параметр - это va_list, который мы используем.
        // Второй параметр - это ожидаемый тип параметров
        int arg = va_arg(list, int);
 
        // Если текущий параметр является контрольным значением, то прекращаем выполнение цикла
        if (arg == -1)
            break;
 
        sum += arg;
        count++;
    }
 
    // Выполняем очистку va_list, когда уже сделали всё необходимое
    va_end(list);
 
    return sum / count;
}
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << findAverage(1, 2, 3, 4, -1) << '\n';
    std::cout << findAverage(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1) << '\n';

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Эллипс, вообще-то, геометрическая фигура :) Что вы имеете в виду на самом деле? Приведите пример кода, может быть...

Comment: что лучше, **макароны** или **visual studio**?

Comment: @timur, конечно макароны....

Comment: элипсес это видимо три точки. Это называется *Функции с переменным числом аргументов*. Они как бы никаким макаром с вектором не соотносятся.

Comment: А может `std::initializer_list`? На Ваш вопрос невозможно дать ответ, т.к. что лучше зависит от конкретной решаемой проблемы.

Comment: Использовать variadic templates или `std::initializer_list`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Освобождая всех от ответственности за мое мнение* (с) Жванецкий, что ли...

Использовать функцию с переменным числом параметров - последнее дело. Потому что нет никакой проверки типов, надо согласовывать, грубо говоря, протокол вызова, чтобы знать, когда закончатся аргументы... Далее, вы по сути не в состоянии динамически изменить количество этих аргументов во время выполнения, после компиляции. Написали руками три аргумента - значит, будет три, и чтоб получить четыре - надо перекомпилировать программу.

Если использовать массив/вектор/еще что-то - это уже куда лучше (по крайней мере, тут вы можете менять динамически размер). Проверка типов... Ну, тут есть варианты. Так, как вы написали - через `void*` - это, скорее всего, с приведением типов, так что строгой типизации и безопасности типов тут не будет, но это уже хоть что-то.

Так что я при прочих равных за нормальные типы данных, а не три точки вместо них :) При этом я не говорю, что их нельзя использовать ни в коем случае - просто надо всегда сопоставлять преимущества и недостатки для каждого конкретного применения.

По поводу быстродействия - не думаю, что влияние будет заметно, потому что отличие будет... ну, на одно разыменование. Так что исходить нужно из критериев, отличных от преждевременной оптимизации :)

Comment: imho время доступа будет одинаковое, а с plain array даже лучше

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, имеется в виду Эллипсис (или неопределённое количество параметров в функции, функция с переменным количеством аргументов), который имеет синтаксис

```
<return_type> function(arg1, ...); //... - и есть эллипсис
```

Полезная в некоторых случаях вещь, однако имеет синтаксис, который быстро забывается в виду крайне нерегулярного его использования (сугубо на мой дилетантский взгляд, конечно же). Прежде чем использовать эллипсис, следует для начала создать переменную типа va_list, которая и хранит массив аргументов эллипсиса. Затем следует инициализировать эту переменную функцией va_start. Аргументы можно получить функцией va_arg, в котором указывается индекс аргумента и его предполагаемый тип данных. Завершается использование эллипсиса вызовом va_end для очистки массива.
Однако же, с вектором мороки будет меньше. Его не требуется инициализировать в самой функции. Да и количество аргументов мы точно знаем, в отличии от эллипсиса, при инициализации которого в функции va_start необходимо указать ПРЕДПОЛАГАЕМОЕ количество аргументов. Но в обоих случаях остаётся минус, связанный с типами данных - мы до конца не знаем какие типы данных имеют аргументы. Поэтому в обоих случаях наверняка необходимо использовать разные методы, например строку-декодер, которая сообщит как трактовать аргументы. Но по производительности эллипсис будет получше, думаю.
В любом случае, тема очень интересна и хотелось бы услышать ответы опытных программистов!